# spring(not able to understand and solve the below error)

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, jsp, server

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/ExpenseSpringProject] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.TransientDataAccessResourceException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [select * from user where email=? and pass=?]; Invalid argument value: java.io.NotSerializableException; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid argument value: java.io.NotSerializableException] with root cause
java.io.NotSerializableException: com.example.dao.UserDao$MyRowMapper
at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1193)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:353)
    at com.mysql.cj.AbstractQueryBindings.setSerializableObject(AbstractQueryBindings.java:1043)
    at com.mysql.cj.AbstractQueryBindings.setObject(AbstractQueryBindings.java:296)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.setObject(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1669)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:409)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValueInternal(StatementCreatorUtils.java:231)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:162)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.ArgumentPreparedStatementSetter.doSetValue(ArgumentPreparedStatementSetter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.ArgumentPreparedStatementSetter.setValues(ArgumentPreparedStatementSetter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:720)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:651)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:713)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:744)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:757)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:810)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForList(JdbcTemplate.java:942)
    at com.example.dao.UserDao.login(UserDao.java:31)
    at com.example.controller.UserController.login(UserController.java:32)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1060)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:962)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1707)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

Comment: error says ```SQL [select * from user where email=? and pass=?]; Invalid argument value:```, check if valid arguments are passed

Answer (score 0):

You must see error

```
com.example.dao.UserDao.login(UserDao.java:31) 
com.example.controller.UserController.login(UserController.java:32)

select * from user where email=? and pass=? 
Probably method parameters are missing or something wrong while passing parameter in  dao.
```

Answer (score 0):

From the error, it looks like something in UserDao is not implementing Serializable. https://www.baeldung.com/java-serialization has some info on serialization, but a starting point is making your class `implements Serializable`.